# Sentry with @sentry/webpack-plugin and heroku

Tags: heroku, webpack, sentry

I'm using webpack to build my app and it works locally with `@sentry/webpack-plugin` – it autogenerates the release and uploads the sourcemaps to Sentry.

However, if I'm trying to build the same app on Heroku it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Command failed: /tmp/build_e3ae44a78c063d6493d3fdfc983bd8d6/client/node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli releases propose-version
  INFO    2019-04-16 13:33:13.141611957 +00:00 Loaded config from /tmp/build_e3ae44a78c063d6493d3fdfc983bd8d6/client/.sentryclirc
  DEBUG   2019-04-16 13:33:13.141666891 +00:00 sentry-cli version: 1.41.0, platform: "linux", architecture: "x86_64"
  INFO    2019-04-16 13:33:13.141684793 +00:00 sentry-cli was invoked with the following command line: "/tmp/build_e3ae44a78c063d6493d3fdfc983bd8d6/client/node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli" "releases" "propose-version"
  DEBUG   2019-04-16 13:33:13.141916192 +00:00 error: running update nagger
  DEBUG   2019-04-16 13:33:13.141939514 +00:00 skipping update nagger because session is not attended
error: Could not automatically determine release name
  DEBUG   2019-04-16 13:33:13.142576118 +00:00 client close; no transport to shut down  (from sentry)
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:289:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:381:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:606:12)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by manually specifying the release name in the plugin config:

```
const version = require('../VERSION').version;

webpackConfig.plugins.push(new SentryWebpackPlugin({
  include: '../src',
  ignoreFile: '.sentrycliignore',
  ignore: ['node_modules', 'webpack.config.js'],
  configFile: '.sentryclirc',
  release: version
}));
```

We use a module called [release-it](https://github.com/release-it/release-it) to build a VERSION file when we run `npm run release`. Here's the `.release-it.json` config file we use for that:

```
{
  "non-interactive": true,
  "npm": {
    "publish": false
  },
  "use": "git.tag",
  "pkgFiles": null,
  "scripts": {
    "afterBump": "echo module.exports = {version: \"'\"${version}\"'\"} > $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/VERSION"
  },
  "git": {
    "commitMessage": "release: v${version}",
    "requireCleanWorkingDir": false,
    "tagName": "v${version}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I build with a slow internet connection.
Also, check if the API token you are using have the write permission in  https://sentry.io/settings/account/api/auth-tokens/