# Sentry.io & Heroku: error: Could not automatically determine release name

Tags: heroku, deployment, build, sentry

## Situation

Our front-end app is hosted by Heroku.
I followed this tutorial: https://docs.sentry.io/guides/integrate-frontend/

### Package.json scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "REACT_APP_RELEASE=`./node_modules/.bin/sentry-cli releases propose-version --log-level=debug` REACT_APP_STAGE=production react-app-rewired build && make setup_release",
    "start": "REACT_APP_RELEASE=`./node_modules/.bin/sentry-cli releases propose-version --log-level=debug` REACT_APP_STAGE=production serve -s ./build",
    ... irrelevant scripts
  },
```

### Makefile

```
SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN=<sentry_auth_token>
SENTRY_ORG=<sentry_org>
SENTRY_PROJECT=<sentry_project>
VERSION=`./node_modules/.bin/sentry-cli releases propose-version --log-level=debug`
PREFIX=static/js

setup_release: create_release upload_sourcemaps

create_release:
    ./node_modules/.bin/sentry-cli releases -o $(SENTRY_ORG) new -p $(SENTRY_PROJECT) $(VERSION) --log-level=debug

upload_sourcemaps:
    ./node_modules/.bin/sentry-cli releases -o $(SENTRY_ORG) -p $(SENTRY_PROJECT) files $(VERSION) \
        upload-sourcemaps --url-prefix "~/$(PREFIX)" --validate build/$(PREFIX) --log-level=debug
```

## Local test

Running `npm run build` locally works competely fine. Gives something like this:

```
Source Map Upload Report
  Minified Scripts
    ~/static/js/0.5d07aaef.chunk.js (sourcemap at 0.5d07aaef.chunk.js.map)
    ~/static/js/1.baafde2d.chunk.js (sourcemap at 1.baafde2d.chunk.js.map)
    ...
    ... more entries
    ...
    ~/static/js/main.8b1cab7e.chunk.js (sourcemap at main.8b1cab7e.chunk.js.map)
    ~/static/js/runtime~main.b6cf63c4.js (sourcemap at runtime~main.b6cf63c4.js.map)

  Source Maps
    ~/static/js/0.5d07aaef.chunk.js.map
    ~/static/js/15.5b79a308.chunk.js.map
    ...
    ... more entries
    ...
    ~/static/js/9.44f0809a.chunk.js.map
    ~/static/js/main.8b1cab7e.chunk.js.map
```

## Heroku deploy test

Running the deploy sequence on Heroku gives the following:

```
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build
remote:        
remote:        > <heroku_project_name>@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_43aa3bf4ce7530858abaf7fc0103a317
remote:        > REACT_APP_RELEASE=`./node_modules/.bin/sentry-cli releases propose-version --log-level=debug` REACT_APP_STAGE=production react-app-rewired build && make setup_release
remote:        
remote:   INFO    2019-10-15 10:29:17.592182558 +00:00 Loaded config from /tmp/build_43aa3bf4ce7530858abaf7fc0103a317/.sentryclirc
remote:   DEBUG   2019-10-15 10:29:17.592238531 +00:00 sentry-cli version: 1.48.0, platform: "linux", architecture: "x86_64"
remote:   INFO    2019-10-15 10:29:17.592260636 +00:00 sentry-cli was invoked with the following command line: "/tmp/build_43aa3bf4ce7530858abaf7fc0103a317/node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli" "releases" "propose-version" "--log-level=debug"
remote:   DEBUG   2019-10-15 10:29:17.592446409 +00:00 error: running update nagger
remote:   DEBUG   2019-10-15 10:29:17.592465389 +00:00 skipping update nagger because session is not attended
remote: error: Could not automatically determine release name
remote:   DEBUG   2019-10-15 10:29:17.592964391 +00:00 client close; no transport to shut down  (from sentry)
```

What is this update nagger thing? Why is it causing this error?

Comment: Possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55710718/sentry-with-sentry-webpack-plugin-and-heroku/58616627#58616627